# Is back of the cab constant?

Tags: vectors

I was reading triple cross product. I had read something just like this :

$$\vec A \times (\vec B \times \vec C)=\vec B(\vec A\cdot \vec C)-\vec C(\vec A\cdot \vec B)$$

which is also called "back of the cab". I know that cross product is vector, like as $$\vec C=\vec A\times \vec B$$
so C is vector. But when I used dot product they are forming a scalar. So my question is do we really use the expression (back of the cab) for magnitude of triple cross product?

$$C=\vec A\cdot \vec B$$

Editing again after seeing Jean's comment (first comment) :

When I used dot product that became scalar as I said earlier so I am going to assume

$$A\cdot B=\alpha \\ C\cdot A=\beta$$

alpha and beta is scalar now but A and B is scalar or vector, who cares? When I multiplied alpha and beta by B respectively with B then I got

$$B\cdot \alpha-\beta \cdot B$$
Now they are scalar. Who says they are vector?

Comment: Good mnemonic indeed ! As your pseudo, I ignored it. Besides, the result is not a magnitude (which is a positive number) but a vector.

Comment: I think there's a typo; the triple product should be equal to $B(A \cdot C) - (C \cdot A)B$?

Comment: @VTand What I wrote? I can't see any difference. Maybe I am not able to read your statement properly.. Could you please suggest an edit so maybe I could take a look

Comment: @JeanMarie What!! Really!? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Proof I think I made a typo somewhere but I can't look properly. m dumb :)

Comment: Explanation: it's an english wording mnemonic, and I have been taught and have taught myself in another language, French.

Comment: 'do we really use the expression (back of the cab) for magnitude of triple cross product?' Not for the *magnitude*, no. Did you mean to include the word 'magnitude' there?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have re-edited my question.. Could you please clarify this time? What's going on here?

Comment: Wait, the correct expression is $B (A \cdot C) - C (A \cdot B)$.

Comment: @VTand same thing, no one cares! If you look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Proof) than you will get something... If you move to [YT video (not for all)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8kCDXEIcZU) you will find what you wrote... If you read Griffths's Electrodynamics than you will get what I wrote ... cheers !

Comment: @Vtand : you are right. This expression can be written $B \alpha - C \beta$ (without the dot product, just multiplication of a vector by a scalar, therefore is a **vector**, not a scalar.

Comment: @JeanMarie Good point..! Wouldn't you like to write an answer? So that I could upvote.. :)

Comment: @Unknown In this case Griffith's Dynamics is wrong : the expression given by Vtand is the only right one... : if you examine the expression you have written, it gives always a multiple of $B$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yep! You are really correct. I have rechecked the book. Now I found it.. Sorry for the mistake also.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double cross product expression:

$$A \times (B \times C) = B \underbrace{(A \cdot C)}_{\alpha \in \mathbb R} - C \underbrace{(A \cdot B)}_{\beta \in \mathbb R}=\alpha B - \beta C$$

is a **vector** belonging to plane defined by $B$ and $C$, therefore orthogonal to $B \times C$ which is very natural when you see its definition...

Its magnitude is $\|\alpha B - \beta C \|$.

Comment: No problem. I remember having spent time to find out solutions involving cross products (and doing repeated calculations errors) . You might be interested by an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493608) of mine mentionning other forms of "repeated cross products".

Comment: See as well this interesting proof using Cauchy-Binet formula: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3975153